# Obter todos os checkbox "marcados" em um lista gerada dinamicamente pelo jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um modal no qual contem uma lista que é gerada dinamicamente pelo *jQuery* por via de um *callback* do *AJAX*.

A questão e que eu preciso obter os id's de todos os *"checkbox's"* que foram selecionados no mesmo. Tenho quase certeza que irei precisar o método `.on()`, mas só não sei como eu possa fazer o mesmo.

Abaixo segue minha lista que é gerada dinamicamente:

```
<ul id="list-of-passenger-service-item" class="list-cadastro skin skin-flat">
   <li>
       <input type="checkbox" id="25">
       <label>Claudia Fernadez - Filho(a) - 09/06/2000</label>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Já tentei algo do tipo, mas infelizmente não obtive sucesso, pois ele "pula" o `.on()`:

```
$(document).on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function() {
    $(this).each(function(){
        console.log('obter os id\'s e armazenar em um array');
    });
});
```

### EDIÇÃO

Tentarei resumir o fluxo para melhor compreensão de todos.

Tenho um botão que tem como objetivo abrir um modal:

```
//Abre o Modal e realiza o append (Exemplo para ilustração do meu caso)
$('#open-modal-item').click(function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#modalItem').modal('show');

    //Chamada AJAX omitida

    $('#list-of-passenger-service-item').append("<li> <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\""+value.id+"\"> <label>" + value.firstName + " " + value.lastName + " - Cônjuge - " + date.toLocaleDateString()  + '</label> </li>');

});
```

Logo, em meu modal tenho um botão que tem como objetivo realizar a confirmação dos dados:

```
$('#service-item-btn-confirm').click(function (event){
   event.preventDefault();

   //Varias linhas foram omitidas para facilitar o entedimento

   //Chamo o metodo que tem como objetivo construir um objeto JSON para posteriormente passar para o back-end
   constructServiceItemObj();
})
```

Finalmente dentro do método `constructServiceItemObj();` eu preciso pegar todos os componentes checkbox's que foram selecionados pelo usuário:

```
function constructServiceItemObj(){
    $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function(i, el){
        var id = $(this).find(':input');
    });

});
```

Infelizmente o mesmo não funciona! Justamente pelo motivo (creio eu) que os elementos da minha lista que comtem o checkbox's são gerados dinamicamente, logo eu precise talvez de um `.on()` no meu `$.each()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você não vai precisar usar o `on()` nesse caso, pois o que você deseja é pegar os IDs em um determinado momento, certo? Como no click de um botão?

Então, considerando que você tenha um botão que ao ser clicado vai pegar esses IDs (pode ser outro evento, o principal aqui é a parte central do código abaixo), você pode usar o seletor `:checked` para pegar os checkboxes que estão marcados.

```js
$("#botaoEnviar").click(function(){
  $("input:checked").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
  });
});
```

Faça o teste e veja se lhe atende.

Comment: Oi Joel creio que eu precise sim do `.on()`, pois toda vez que eu entro em meu "modal" `$('#open-modal-item').click(function (event){});` eu realizo uma chamada ajax, na qual tem objetivo de retornar valores que serão "appendados" dinamicamente. Logo acredito que o uso do  `.on()` torna-se necessario. Eu testei o exemplo que você me passou, mas infelizmente o mesmo não funcionou.

Comment: Fiz um pequeno exemplo, veja se é mais ou menos parecido com o que você precisa: https://jsfiddle.net/xsqb7a6s/. Nele não usei o `.on`.

Comment: Joel, finalmente funcionou. Mas tive que fazer uma alteração. No meu componente de `<ul>` eu tinha duas classe **css** denominadas: `.skin .skin-flat`, logo todos os casos citados aqui funcionaram! O problema aparentemente eram essas duas classes que estavam impedimento o funcionamente, só não sei ao certo qual o motivo.

Answer (score 3):

Para selecionares os checkbox precisas de um seletor CSS que inclua o que queres.

`input[type="checkbox"]` faz isso, ou até o pseudo-seletor do jQuery `":checkbox"`. Porém deves também usar uma classe ou elemento do DOM em comum para garantir que só apanhas os inputs que queres.

Para selectionar:

```
var inputs = $('.lista-cadastros :checkbox');
```

eventualmente usando o `:checked` para filtrar os que não estão marcados

para saber os IDs:

```
var ids = inputs.map(function(){
    return this.id;
});
```

se precisares de uma array nativa e não um objeto jQuery podes chamar o `.get();` no fim:

```
var ids = inputs.map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

A segunda parte em que escreves "*preciso obter os id's de todos os checkbox's que foram selecionados no mesmo*" pode precisar do `.on()`. Na pergunta não é claro qual momento em que precisas de correr esse código. No caso de o elemento que aciona esse código ter sido adicionado dinamicamente então sim precisas do `.on()` com delegação. No caso mais simples podes usar:

```
$(document).on('click', 'seletor-para-o-elemento', function(){
```

Comment: Olá Sergio! Edite4i a pergunta para que fique mais clara a minha necessidade. Mas provavelmente eu precise do `.on()`.

Comment: @JoãoManolo e esses inputs estão dentro do mesmo `<ul>`?

Comment: @JoãoManolo seria algo assim? -> http://jsfiddle.net/9Lcv99xe/

Comment: infelizmente não funcionou! Não consigo entender o motivo. Quando vou "debbugar" o documento .js ele simplesmente pula a função!